# Meta tags from pages are missing in page source

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I am having the Nextjs-based Web App for my Portfolio Website, where I've defined some common meta tags in the `_document.jsx` file and I have a few static pages in which in the browser tab I can see the title, but when I open the Page Source those titles are missing.

My `_document.jsx` file code are below:

```js
// Next
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document';
import Script from 'next/script';

// styled-components
import { ServerStyleSheet } from 'styled-components';

const APP_NAME = `Dhaval Vira Resume | CV | Portfolio`;
const APP_DESC = `A skilled full-stack developer who has worked on projects ranging from small personal sites to large enterprise systems.`;
const APP_URL = `https://dhavalvira.com`;

class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet();
    const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;

    try {
      ctx.renderPage = () =>
        originalRenderPage({
          enhanceApp: (Component) => (props) =>
            sheet.collectStyles(<Component {...props} />),
        });

      const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);
      return {
        ...initialProps,
        styles: [initialProps.styles, sheet.getStyleElement()],
      };
    } finally {
      sheet.seal();
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Html lang='en-US'>
        <Head>
          {/* General Meta Tags */}
          <meta charSet='utf-8' />
          <meta httpEquiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge' />
          <link rel='icon' href='/favicon.ico' />

          {/* Meta Tags */}
          <meta name='application-name' content={APP_NAME} />
          <meta name='description' content={APP_DESC} />
          <meta name='author' content='Dhaval Vira' />
          <meta name='robots' content='index, follow' />
          <meta name='rating' content='general' />
          <link rel='canonical' href={APP_URL} />
          <meta httpEquiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />
          <meta name='language' content='English' />
          <meta name='revisit-after' content='1 day' />
          <meta name='creationdate' content='14-Feb-2022' />
          <meta name='distribution' content='global' />
          <meta
            name='keywords'
            content='CV, resume, online cv, online resume, professional resume, portfolio, next js developer, nextjs developer, freelance developer, full stack developer, full-stack developer, freelance full stack developer, freelance full-stack developer, freelance next js developer, freelance next.js developer, freelance nextjs developer'
          />

          {/* Open Graph */}
          <meta property='og:url' content={APP_URL} />
          <meta property='og:type' content='website' />
          <meta property='og:title' content={APP_NAME} />
          <meta property='og:description' content={APP_DESC} />
          <meta property='og:image' content='/D_V_Cropped.png' />

          {/* Twitter Meta Tags */}
          <meta name='twitter:card' content='summary_large_image' />
          <meta property='twitter:domain' content={APP_URL} />
          <meta property='twitter:url' content={APP_URL} />
          <meta name='twitter:title' content={APP_NAME} />
          <meta name='twitter:description' content={APP_DESC} />
          <meta name='twitter:image' content='/D_V_Cropped.png' />

          {/* Some Extra Tags */}
          <meta name='apple-mobile-web-app-capable' content='yes' />
          <meta
            name='apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style'
            content='default'
          />
          <meta name='apple-mobile-web-app-title' content={APP_NAME} />
          <meta name='description' content={APP_DESC} />
          <meta name='format-detection' content='telephone=no' />
          <meta name='mobile-web-app-capable' content='yes' />
          <meta name='theme-color' content='#000000' />
          <link rel='manifest' href='/manifest.json' />
          <link rel='apple-touch-icon' href='/D_V_Cropped.png' />

          {/* Icons */}
          <link
            rel='apple-touch-icon'
            sizes='57x57'
            href='/icons/apple-icon-57x57.png'
          />
          <link
            rel='apple-touch-icon'
            sizes='60x60'
            href='/icons/apple-icon-60x60.png'
          />
          <link
            rel='apple-touch-icon'
            sizes='72x72'
            href='/icons/apple-icon-72x72.png'
          />
          <link
            rel='apple-touch-icon'
            sizes='76x76'
            href='/icons/apple-icon-76x76.png'
          />
          <link
            rel='apple-touch-icon'
            sizes='114x114'
            href='/icons/apple-icon-114x114.png'
          />
          <link
            rel='apple-touch-icon'
            sizes='120x120'
            href='/icons/apple-icon-120x120.png'
          />
          <link
            rel='apple-touch-icon'
            sizes='144x144'
            href='/icons/apple-icon-144x144.png'
          />
          <link
            rel='apple-touch-icon'
            sizes='152x152'
            href='/icons/apple-icon-152x152.png'
          />
          <link
            rel='apple-touch-icon'
            sizes='180x180'
            href='/icons/apple-icon-180x180.png'
          />
          <link
            rel='apple-touch-icon'
            sizes='192x192'
            href='/icons/apple-icon-precomposed.png'
          />
          <link
            rel='icon'
            type='image/png'
            sizes='192x192'
            href='/icons/android-icon-192x192.png'
          />
          <link
            rel='icon'
            type='image/png'
            sizes='32x32'
            href='/icons/favicon-32x32.png'
          />
          <link
            rel='icon'
            type='image/png'
            sizes='96x96'
            href='/icons/favicon-96x96.png'
          />
          <link
            rel='icon'
            type='image/png'
            sizes='16x16'
            href='/icons/favicon-16x16.png'
          />
          <meta name='msapplication-TileColor' content='#54ca95' />
          <meta name='msapplication-TileImage' content='/ms-icon-144x144.png' />
          <meta name='msapplication-TileImage' content='/ms-icon-150x150.png' />
          <meta name='msapplication-TileImage' content='/ms-icon-310x310.png' />
          <meta name='theme-color' content='#54ca95' />

          {/* Google Tag Manager */}
          // GTM iFrame Tag

          {/* LinkedIn Insight Tags */}
          // LinkedIn Insight Scrip Tags

          {/* Google Tag Manager */}
          // Google Tag Manager Script Tag
          </Script>

          {/* Schema.org */}
          // Schema.org Script Tag
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}

export default MyDocument;
```

Below code is from `blogs.jsx` in which the title inside the `<Head></Head>` tag remains static `<Head><title>Blog :: Dhaval Vira Resume</title></Head>`. this title is visible in the Chrome Tab, but when I open the Page Source, that time it's missing.

Below is the code from `pages/blog/[index].js` Page, and when I open the below Page Source - all those Meta Tags are missing.

```js
const BlogPost = (props) => {
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    Prism.highlightAll();
  }, []);

  // destructuring props
  const { singleData, ...other } = props;

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Head>
        <title>{singleData[0].blogTitle} :: Dhaval Vira Resume</title>
        <meta name='description' content={singleData[0].seoDescription} />
        <meta name='keywords' content={singleData[0].tags.map((tag) => tag)} />

        {/* OG Meta Tags */}
        <meta property='og:title' content={singleData[0].seoTitle} />
        <meta
          property='og:description'
          content={singleData[0].seoDescription}
        />
        <meta property='og:type' content='article' />
        <meta
          property='og:url'
          content={`${process.env.SHARE_URL}${router.asPath}`}
        />
        <meta
          name='image'
          property='og:image'
          content={singleData[0].displayImageUrl}
        />

        {/* Twitter Meta Tags */}
        <meta property='twitter:title' content={singleData[0].seoTitle} />
        <meta
          property='twitter:description'
          content={singleData[0].seoDescription}
        />
        <meta
          property='twitter:image'
          content={singleData[0].displayImageUrl}
        />
        <link
          rel='canonical'
          href={`${process.env.SHARE_URL}${router.asPath}`}
        />
      </Head>

      <div>{/* HTML Code goes here */}</div>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default BlogPost;

export const getServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  const { index } = context.params;

  const response = await axios({
    url: `${process.env.SERVER_URL}/api/get-single-blog-detail?slug=${index}`,
    method: 'GET',
    validateStatus: function (status) {
      return status >= 200 && status < 599;
    },
  });

  switch (response.status) {
    case 200:
      return {
        props: {
          singleData: response.data.comments,
        },
      };
    case 500:
      return {
        redirect: {
          destination: '/500',
          permanent: false,
        },
      };
    default:
      return {
        redirect: {
          destination: '/404',
          permanent: false,
        },
      };
  }
};
```

Also, if I'm sharing the link of my Portfolio Site with anyone (WhatsApp or LinkedIn) at that place also when the title is coming up, it's coming from either Static Page or Dynamic Page, it's coming from `_document.jsx` file.

Below is the `_app.jsx` code:

```js
// React
import React, { Fragment, useEffect, useState } from 'react';

// next component
import Head from 'next/head';
import Router from 'next/router';

// Preloader Component
import Loader from '../Loader/loader';

// react-hot-toast
import { Toaster } from 'react-hot-toast';

// NProgress Package & CSS
import NProgress from 'nprogress';
import '../styles/nprogress.css';

Router.events.on('routeChangeStart', NProgress.start);
Router.events.on('routeChangeError', NProgress.done);
Router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', NProgress.done);

import '../styles/globals.css';

// Google Firebase - Analytics - SDK
import { getAnalytics, logEvent } from 'firebase/analytics';

// Utils Func for Firebase
import { app } from '../utils/firebase';

function MyApp(props) {
  const { Component, pageProps } = props;

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setLoading(false);
    }, 4000);
  }, []);

  if (loading) {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Head>
          <title>Dhaval Vira Resume</title>
          <meta
            name='description'
            content='online resume website of Dhaval Vira, cv of Dhaval Vira, portfolio of Dhaval Vira'
          />
          <link rel='icon' href='/favicon.ico' />
        </Head>
        <Loader />
      </Fragment>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Head>
          <title>Dhaval Vira Resume</title>
          <meta
            name='description'
            content='online resume website of Dhaval Vira, cv of Dhaval Vira, portfolio of Dhaval Vira'
          />
          <link rel='icon' href='/favicon.ico' />
        </Head>

        <Component {...pageProps} />

        {/* react-hot-toast */}
        <Toaster position='top-right' reverseOrder={false} />
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default MyApp;
```

Comment: Can you show us your `_app` page as well?

Comment: sure, I'm sharing the code block, in multiple comments

Comment: @juliomalves = I've added the code of `_app.js` to the question, please check....

Comment: You're client-side rendering your pages after 4s have passed, the meta tags you've defined in the pages will only be available then. You're getting the `Loader` component during server-side rendering.

Comment: @juliomalves Sir, if I remove the `<Loader />` which is rendering after 4s, then I can able to see the meta tags on the dynamic blog page?

Comment: No, you need to remove the loading logic entirely. Just render the page component straight away, so it can be server-side rendered.

Comment: @juliomalves Sir, I've removed the loading logic completely, and now I'm checking the dynamic blog page's page source, and now it's showing me the meta tags I've defined.

Answer (score 0):

In `_app.jsx`, you're forcing client-side rendering of your pages content after 4s have passed due the the loading logic you have there. This means that when the pages gets pre-rendered on the server you're only getting the `Loader` component in the HTML sent from the server.

Remove the loading logic entirely so that your pages can be server-side rendered properly.

```js
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <Head>
                <title>Dhaval Vira Resume</title>
                <meta
                    name='description'
                    content='online resume website of Dhaval Vira, cv of Dhaval Vira, portfolio of Dhaval Vira'
                />
                <link rel='icon' href='/favicon.ico' />
            </Head>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
            {/* react-hot-toast */}
            <Toaster position='top-right' reverseOrder={false} />
        </Fragment>
    );
}
```